# Отправка post запроса с получением ответа

Tags: php, post, запрос

Мне нужно отправить POST запрос через PHP Без CURL.
После отправки запроса, сервер высылает ответ об ошибке или результат. 
Мне нужно что бы я мог задать значения которые я отправляю, а после получения ответа сохранить его в переменную. 
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: а почему без cURL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без cURL можно отправить POST запрос через [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php) используя параметр `context` (список параметров для функции [stream_context_create()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.stream-context-create.php) в документации [Опции контекста HTTP](http://php.net/manual/ru/context.http.php)):

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'var1' => 'some content',
        'var2' => 'doh'
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/submit.php', false, $context);
```

**P.S.** Подобный вопрос был задан на [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445276/how-to-post-data-in-php-using-file-get-contents#answer-2445332).

Answer (score 0):

Просто дам ссылку, чтобы не дублировать: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php

В комментариях есть нужный вам пример кода.

Answer (score 0):

Уважаемый я указал как можно реализовыввать переменную через форму,если что можете задавать другие вопросы.POST-GET это методы отправки которые вы хотите.
`

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST(GET)['Имя для кнопки'])){
$переменная = $_POST(GET)['переменная с формы'];
} 
?>
<form method="POST(GET)">
<input type="text" name="перемменая с формы" >
<input type="submit" name="Имя для кнопки">
</form>
```

`